# Passing values using partial functions

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, partial, signals-slots

I am using a partial function to pass a value to a function argument, on a click of a QPushButton.

```
self.SearchButton1 = QPushButton("Search")
self.SearchStudent1 = QLineEdit()
```

Below is how it is connected:

```
self.connect(self.SearchButton1, SIGNAL("clicked()"),
             partial(self.Searching, self.SearchStudent1.text()))
```

The called function is as below:

```
def Searching(self, num):
    print self.SearchStudent1.text()
    print num
```

I am not sure why `num` is not getting printed, whereas `self.SearchStudent1.text()` gets printed correctly on the press of the 'Search' button.

Please suggest if I am missing anything.

**EDIT**:

I can anyhow pass the QLineEdit object using partial function and work with it:

```
self.connect(self.SearchButton1, SIGNAL("clicked()"),
             partial(self.Searching, self.SearchStudent1))

def Searching(self, num):
    print self.SearchStudent1.text()
    print num.text() # works fine
```

Answer (score 0):

The [partial function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) will cache the arguments passed to it. So if the line-edit is empty when the signal is connected, an empty string will always be sent to the called method. (It's always a good idea to use `repr` when debugging with `print`, so that you can easily see output values like `""` or `None`).

If you want the current text is be sent to the slot when the button is clicked, you can use a `lambda` function, like this:

```
self.connect(self.SearchButton1, SIGNAL("clicked()"),
             lambda: self.Searching(self.SearchStudent1.text())
```

Or more simply:

```
self.SearchButton1.clicked.connect(
    lambda: self.Searching(self.SearchStudent1.text())
```